# Unable to find translated text in messages YAML file SF2 project

Tags: php, symfony, controller, translation, php-5.3

I have the following code in my controller where I am attempting to output the translation of 'GalleryThanksMessage' to the user by feeding it through to the Twig template.

The classes/namespaces included are:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller,
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route,
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template,
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

// Redirect the user and add a thank you flash message
// The string 'GalleryThanksMessage' can now be overwritten by a translation
$message = $this->get('translator')->trans('GalleryThanksMessage');
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('gallery_thanks', array('message' => $message));
```

In my `BundleName/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml` I have the following:

```
'GalleryThanksMessage':  Thanks!
```

However, this pulls through as "GalleryThanksMessage" to the front-end Twig template.

I have a similar setup for another page and bundle on my site and I am having trouble working out what is missing.

I've had a read of [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-configuration), but it doesn't help me point out why this isn't pulling through.

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache? When you add/remove translation, you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your example this should be working

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator:        { fallback: "%locale%" }
```

---

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    locale: en
```

---

```
# Acme/MyBundle/Controller/WelcomeController.php
public function myAction(){
    // Get the message
    $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('GalleryThanksMessage');
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('gallery_thanks', array('message' => $message));
    return array('message' => $message); // or whatever
}
```

---

```
# Acme/MyBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml
GalleryThanksMessage: This is a cool message!
```

Of course, you would need to clean your `app/cache/` directory after you make any changes for this to work.

Comment: Many thanks, a `php app/console cache:clear` done the trick. I wasn't aware that the cache had to be cleared after adding a translation. Noted ;)